# S3 Redirection Rules Unable to redirect a url path to an external website with QueryString

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On AWS we created an s3 bucket as a website with a url redirect,

we have an s3 bucket http://routing.test.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

using this request with a query string param

http://routing.test.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SLAManager?app=continue

we're trying to redirect requests from   http://routing.test.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/  to domain.salesforce.com/SLAManager?app=continue

We created an s3 bucket with static website hosting using the following

```
<RoutingRules>  
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>SLAManager</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>domain.salesforce.com</HostName>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>      
      <ReplaceKeyWith>SLAManager/</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>   
</RoutingRules>
```

This is not working, the query string parameter is lost after redirection,

we need the query string to access the public URL without authentication 
Is this possible to preserve the query string on during redirect?  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `<ReplaceKeyWith>`.  This clears out the entire URI (path + query string) from the internal buffer that S3 is using to write the redirect, and replaces it with the value shown.

If you change this to `<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>` the bucket behaves as expected.

Because you can't use `<ReplaceKeyWith>` in this application, you'll probably want two rules, the first one testing `<KeyPrefixEquals>SLAManager/</KeyPrefixEquals>` and the second one testing `<KeyPrefixEquals>SLAManager</KeyPrefixEquals>`.  The reason for this is related to your use of the trailing `/` on the end of the new key, which I assume the target system requires.  For both rules, use `<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>SLAManager/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>`.

Comment: shoutout! Thanks Michael, this worked but with some modifications to the RoutingRule

Comment: <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith> works for this scenario.  
However, I need to change the RoutingRules to remove the trailing slash for this to work, I also added some <HttpRedirectCode>

`<RoutingRules>  
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>SLAManager</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>domain.salesforce.com</HostName>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>      
      <ReplaceKeyWith>SLAManager</ReplaceKeyWith>
   <HttpRedirectCode>302</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>   
</RoutingRules>`

Comment: Ah, okay.  I included the `/` because you had it in the original question, so I assumed you needed to be there for some reason.  Please consider marking the answer as accepted unless there is anything I can clarify.